# Can't call a function with arrays chunks, get undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to dynamically populate a shelf with books. I split an array into many arrays depending of the number of books on the shelf. Then I call a function create which creates a shelf and populates every shelf according to a number of books. The error I have is "create(arrayOfArrays[y]) is undefined". The function doesn't want to be called with my arrays.  [Link to my pen](https://codepen.io/JulieJones/pen/ExjxzJE)

```
var arrayOfArrays = [];
var arr = ['1.png','2.png','3.png','4.png','5.png','6.png']

 for (var i=0; i<arra.length; i+=numberOfBooks) {
    arrayOfArrays.push(arra.slice(i,i+numberOfBooks));
  }

 for(y=0; y<arrayOfArrays.length; y++){
     create(arrayOfArrays[y]) 
   }

function create(arra) { 
   var shelf = document.createElement('div');
   shelf.className = "shelf";
        var base = document.createElement('div');
        var shelfBackground = document.createElement('div');      
        var shelfImages = document.createElement('div');

        shelfBackground.className = "shelf-background";
        base.className = "base";
        shelfImages.className = "shelf-images";        
        shelfBackground.appendChild(base);
        shelf.appendChild(shelfBackground);
        shelf.append(shelfImages);
        wrap.appendChild(shelf);        

         arra.forEach(function(i, arra) {
            var shelfImage = document.createElement('div');
             shelfImage.className = 'shelf-image';
             var image = document.createElement('img');
             image.src = arra[i]
             shelfImage.append(image);
             shelfImages.append(shelfImage);
        }); 
   }
```

Comment: Could you please check your code again and provide us code for the reproducing?
I can not reproduce you're issue because `àrra` and `numberOfBooks` are undefined.

Comment: `create(arrayOfArrays[y]) is undefined` because that is what it returns.

Comment: @Kinimod  Please check a pen. I have a link below.

Comment: @AZ_ I understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue lies in the foreach loop:

Here I fixed it for you:

```
 arra.forEach(function(element,i) { // The first argument is the element, second is the index
    var shelfImage = document.createElement("div");
    shelfImage.className = "shelf-image";
    var image = document.createElement("img"); 
    image.src = element; // function receives the current element of the array (not the whole array)
    shelfImage.append(image);
    shelfImages.append(shelfImage);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for yout help and explanation! This is not where I thought the error lies...